# The Hilbert transform of analytic function is still analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis

If a function $f$ is analytic in the strip $\mathcal{D}_d = \left\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |\Im(z)| < d \right\}$, how to show that the Hilbert transform of $f$, which is $\mathcal{H}f(x) = p.v. \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{f(t)}{x-t}dt$ ($p.v.$ means Cauchy principal value), is also analytic in this strip?

Comment: What is the Hilbert transform in this setting?

Comment: @Yikai I'm a green hand. Thank you!

Comment: @zhw. $\mathcal{H}f(x) = p.v. \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{f(t)}{x-t} dt$, where p.v. is the Cauchy principal value.

Comment: @Yikai 谢谢你！我自己也正在看handbook

Comment: Can you elaborate on your definition of the Hilbert transform? If $f$ is the exponential function, for example, it doesn't seem to be defined. (I suggest editing the additional details into your question. Comments are good for notifying users who have commented, but others expect to see all details in the question itself.)

Comment: One other thing: I warmly recommend going through the [site tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). You know have enough reputation to vote up any questions and answers you find helpful.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Thank you! I've added the details in the question.

Comment: As was already pointed out, this isn't defined, you need some kind of decay of $f$. If we ignore this issue, then one possible argument goes as follows: $f$ holomorphic on the strip is essentially characterized by $|\widehat{f}(k)|\lesssim e^{-d|k|}$ (again, this needs extra assumptions to make it correct), and the Hilbert transform is the multiplier $\textrm{sign}|k|$, so won't disturb this condition.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Why $f$ holomorphic on the strip is equivalent with its Fourier transform is bounded by $e^{-|d|k}$?

Answer (score 3):

I have enough reputation that I can see a deleted answer.  And that answer seems correct to me.

Of course, there is a problem of defining $\mathcal{H}f(x) = \text{p.v.} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{f(t)}{x-t}\,dt$ for functions that are analytic on $\mathcal{D}_d = \left\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |\Im(z)| < d \right\}$.  But if the function $f$ is sufficiently bounded (e.g. $|\hat f(\zeta)| \le C e^{-(d+\epsilon)|\zeta|}$ for all $\zeta \in \mathbb R$ and some $\epsilon>0$), so that the Hilbert transform is well defined, then one could argue like this:
$$ \frac d{dz} \mathcal{H}f(z) = \frac d{dz} \text{p.v.}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{f(z-t)}{t}\,dt = \text{p.v.}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{f'(z-t)}{t}\,dt .$$
Or if you feel squeamish about pulling the derivative inside of the integral, instead use a contour integral:
$$ \oint_\gamma \mathcal{H}f(z) \, dz = \text{p.v.}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\oint_\gamma f(z-t)\, dz}{t}\,dt = 0 $$
and then use Morea's Theorem.